# Is it safe to go native ES6 now for mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ecmascript-6

I am making a web app for mid this year to run on any device, I don't want to use transpilers or anything like that, but just want to use native es6 syntax for javascript.

I wanted to know if this is a good idea now, and what the minimum versions are that supports es6 for like safari on iphone, safari on mac, chrome on desktop, android and iOS, etc...

Mainly the features I was looking to use in es6 are import/export and class/extend. I found this site https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

but I am not sure how to tell on this, as it is confusing. Like which one is chrome for android/ios, the only chrome I see is CH, which us under desktop browsers. Also on the left side, I see nothing about import/export.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: It's unlikely the installed base of mobile devices you want to support is ready for that.  Just transpile and be done.  You have to look at the marketshare of different versions of IOS and Android and determine which older versions do not support ES6 and whether you're willing to deal with not supporting them.

Comment: Perhaps not what you asked, but I think it might be useful for you to check out [ionic framework] (https://ionicframework.com/) (Sorry for making it an answer, I was _sure_ I was just adding a comment..)

Comment: You have to remember that on Android Chrome is not the only browser.  You can't assume it will even be present.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of links, but the initial conclusion is that neither import or export are natively supported in the browser at this time:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Browser_compatibility

Your best bet is to develop your code, run it through a compiler, and focus you attention on development, feature creation, and a successful launch. It will save you a lot of time and many headaches.